# SMO restore from networked SQLServer never finishes (called from C#)

Tags: c#, smo, database-restore

I try to copy a database from a networked SQLServer to a local SQLExpress:

```
private void DoRestore()
    {
         if (!File.Exists(fileNach))
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Restore gescheitert " + fileNach);
             return;
         }

        Restore res = new Restore();
        Server srv = new Server(Environment.MachineName.ToString()+@"\SQLEXPRESS");
        //MessageBox.Show("Ziel Server :"+srv.Name);

        try
        {
            string fileName = @fileNach;
            string databaseName = "Outdoor";
            srv.KillAllProcesses(databaseName);
            res.Database = databaseName;
            res.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
            res.Devices.AddDevice(fileName, DeviceType.File);
            res.ReplaceDatabase = true;
            res.NoRecovery = true;

            string odb;
            string odblog;
            odb = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Outdoor.mdf";
            odblog = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Outdoor.ldf";

            res.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile("Outdoor", odb));
            res.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile("Outdoor_Log", odblog));

            // restore starten
            res.SqlRestore(srv);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
}
```

This code starts a restore process on the SQLExpress but never ends. The mdf and log files are created in the destination directory but the restore does not finalize.

I also tried with `srv.KillAllProcesses(databaseName);` but no result.

No error is raised at the C# level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say it never ends, is what your seeing that your code finishes but the database is stuck in "restoring" mode? If so, I think you want to restore with recovery, otherwise you're leaving the database non-operational. Try setting NoRecovery to false instead of true:

```
res.NoRecovery = false;
```

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177446.aspx)

1. Leave the database ready for use by rolling back the uncommitted
   transactions. Additional transaction logs cannot be restored.
   (**RESTORE WITH RECOVERY**)

   Recovers the database. This option is equivalent to the RECOVERY
   option in a Transact-SQL RESTORE statement.

   Choose this option only if you have no log files you want to
   restore.
2. Leave the database non-operational, and do not roll back the
   uncommitted transactions. Additional transaction logs can be
   restored. (**RESTORE WITH NORECOVERY**)

   Leaves the database in an unrecovered state. This option is
   equivalent to using the NORECOVERY option in a Transact-SQL RESTORE
   statement.

   When you choose this option, the Preserve replication settings
   option is unavailable.